# Swap values in cols where equal to value - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to determine the most efficient method to swap values in a pandas df. Using the df below, where `Item` is equal to `Left` I want to swap cols `A-D` and `B-C`. The df is quite large though (> 1,000,000 rows) so I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to subset out all values == `Left` and just swap the col headers and then merge back with original df.

So:

```
A1 > D1
B1 > C1
C1 > B1
D1 > A1

A2 > D2
B2 > C2
C2 > B2
D2 > A2

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Item' : ['L','L','R','R','R'],         
    'A1' : ['A','B','C','D','E'],  
    'B1' : ['A','B','C','D','E'],                  
    'C1' : [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'D1' : [1,2,3,4,5],           
    'A2' : ['A','B','C','D','E'],  
    'B2' : ['A','B','C','D','E'],                  
    'C2' : [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'D2' : [1,2,3,4,5],            
        })

def swap(idf, cswap, condition):

    idx = idf[condition].index

    for original,newcol in cswap.items():
        ovalues = idf.loc[idx, original].values
        idf.loc[idx, original] = idf.loc[idx, newcol].values
        idf.loc[idx, newcol] = ovalues

        return idf

df = swap(df, {'A1': 'D1', 'B1': 'C1', 'A2': 'D2', 'B2': 'C2'}, df['Item'] == 'L')
```

Out:

```
  Item A1 B1  C1 D1 A2 B2  C2  D2
0    L  1  A   1  A  A  A   1   1
1    L  2  B   2  B  B  B   2   2
2    R  C  C   3  3  C  C   3   3
3    R  D  D   4  4  D  D   4   4
4    R  E  E   5  5  E  E   5   5
```

Intended Output:

```
  Item  A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
0    L  1   1   A   A   1   1   A   A
1    L  2   2   B   B   2   2   B   B
2    R  C   C   3   3   C   C   3   3
3    R  D   D   4   4   D   D   4   4
4    R  E   E   5   5   E   E   5   5
```

Comment: Just to be clear `L 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` will become `L 4 3 2 1 8 7 6 5`?

Comment: I've updated the question @QuangHoang

Comment: You only have to swap the values in the list of columns. For the give code you can try `df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('1', '2') if '1' in x else x.replace('2', '1'))`,

Comment: This doesn't quite work. The integers are an example. They could represent any data type. I only want to swap values where `Item` is equal to `L` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `swap` function defined below, for the problem.

Inputs:

`cswap` is the dictionary where `(key, value)` represents the columns you want to swap.

`condition` is **True** for `rows` where, we want to execute the swap. e.g., `Item == 'L'`

```py
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  Item  A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
0    L   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
1    L   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
2    R   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
3    R   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
4    R   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1

In [18]: def swap(idf, cswap, condition):
    ...:     idx = idf[condition].index
    ...:     for original,newcol in cswap.items():
    ...:         ovalues = idf.loc[idx, original].values
    ...:         idf.loc[idx, original] = idf.loc[idx, newcol].values
    ...:         idf.loc[idx, newcol] = ovalues
    ...:     return idf

In [22]: swap(df, {'A1': 'D1', 'B1': 'C1', 'A2': 'D2', 'B2': 'C2'}, df['Item'] == 'L')
Out[22]:
  Item  A1  B1  C1  D1  A2  B2  C2  D2
0    L   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   2
1    L   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   2
2    R   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
3    R   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
4    R   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks @DOOM. I'll just add another example. This only seems to change `A1` and `D1`

Comment: @jonboy I was able to match the test output. NOTE: You have to provide the `cswap` dictionary for which you want to `swap` values.

Comment: @jonboy Your **return statement is inside the `for` loop** !!